# cross join in spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

There are two entity

```
@Entity
public class Event{
...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<EventGroup> eventGroups;
}

@Entity
public class EventGroup {
...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Event> events;
}
```

I need to get Events which has EventGroups with given ids.
Using spring data CrudRepository.

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
}
```

Im calling

```
eventRepository.findAll(buildSpecification(filter);
```

This is how i build specification:

```
    private Specification<Event> buildSpecification(final EventFilter filter) {
        final Specification<Event> specification = new Specification<Event>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Event> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                root = criteriaQuery.distinct(true).from(Event.class);
                Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();
                if (filter.getEventGroupIds() != null) {
                    Join<Event, EventGroup> join = root.join(Event_.eventGroups);
                    predicate.getExpressions().add( join.get(EventGroup_.id).in(filter.getEventGroupIds()) );
                }
                return criteriaQuery.where(predicate).getRestriction();
            }
        };
        return specification;
    }
```

But result query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  event0_.id        AS id1_1_,
  event0_.createdAt AS createdA2_1_,
  event0_.date      AS date3_1_,
  event0_.image_id  AS image_id6_1_,
  event0_.moderated AS moderate4_1_,
  event0_.name      AS name5_1_,
  event0_.owner_id  AS owner_id7_1_
FROM Event event0_ 
  CROSS JOIN Event event1_
  INNER JOIN Event_EventGroup eventgroup2_ ON event1_.id = eventgroup2_.Event_id
  INNER JOIN EventGroup eventgroup3_ ON eventgroup2_.eventGroups_id = eventgroup3_.id
WHERE eventgroup3_.id IN (15)
```

This cross join corrupt everything.

What should i do? May be there is another way to get it?

Comment: you dont need to do a `JOIN` _AT_ _ALL_ - simply retrieve the eventgroup with `root.get(Event_.eventGroups)` and use `cb.in( ... )`
By the way : why are you using `CrudRepository` when you have `Repository`?

Comment: Thanks! But in this way i should pass eventGroups but not eventGroupsIds. But it is not a problem. Do you mean @Repository annotation? I just follow spring instructions)

Comment: you're doing something horribly wrong if you keep `PRIMARYKEY`s in some collection in your code - thats bad application design. You should keep detached entities instead - if your amount of entities is small this is also pretty efficient

Comment: I get EventGroupIds from Frontend side. So i think it is ok.

Comment: you are actually TRANSMITTING PRIMARYKEYS over the internet?? Thats .... the worst application design i have ever heard of, it will be hacked the moment it goes live.

Comment: Hmm, i will think about it. But what is problem if somebody knows primary keys?

Comment: literally everything - thats the MAIN security whole which has been used for decades now in literally tens of thousands of content management systems - once an attacker has internal data he can start attacking, if there is no internal data attacks are MUCH more difficult. I think you should do a bit of research before you start developing a CMS.

Comment: Thanks. Ill research it. The reason i did it is : i check acces to entity if needed. But in most cases there is no secret entity and all data is accessible

Comment: if your CMS is publicly available you are essentially violating data privacy acts of many countries.

Answer (score 2):

Solved

```
    private Specification<Event> buildSpecification(final EventFilter filter) {
        final Specification<Event> specification = new Specification<Event>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Event> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                cq.distinct(true);
                Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();
                if (filter.getEventGroupIds() != null) {
                    Join<Event, EventGroup> join = root.join(Event_.eventGroups);
                    predicate.getExpressions().add(join.get(EventGroup_.id).in(filter.getEventGroupIds()) );
                }
                return predicate;
            }
        };
        return specification;
    }
```